# Visual element getting too much attention in heat map

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, information-design, heatmaps

I have a landing page about a service, and after some weeks of testing with beta users I found in my heat map that there is an element in the bottom of the page that have an huge bunch of clicks.

Well, that element is just informative, representing something like "scroll down" implicitly. So, it doesn't have any action when clicked.

Here is the element:

[image]

[image]

And a similar [demo](https://codepen.io/2xsamurai/pen/WwmjKQ).

My question is, what should I do. Remove the element? Make some action or redirect when clicked?

I can't have an element that attract so many attention without any relevant action.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the element is gaining attraction because users don't know what it is and try to interact with it. So users might be asking themselves *"What is this element?" "Am I suppose to interact with it?" "Why isn't it responding after I click?"*. Probably it is not being understood that it is an indicator and not an element to interact with. If this is not understood, after clicking it the user might not know why it is not responding to their click. Do you have any problem with people missing the scroll after they click it?
You could:

- Make the element interactable in case users click it to transmit the message (although this has the risk to be understood as "if you want to scroll you **need** to click")
- Use an element, to indicate that the user should scroll, that can't be confused with an interactable element (explicit text?)
- **Don't use any indicator and rethink the layout of the page so it is understood there is content below that edge**, that needs a scroll interaction

My suggestion is to go for the last one if it is possible.

Comment: Another option could be add opacity that makes that element less relevant, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This means the element is getting too much attention due to an error in design or unable to figure it out in the first look.
as this is related to scroll. you can
 1. add a tooltip to indicate its purpose
 2. change the design like giving a text.
 3. create an interaction which scrolls to next page if possible as the user expects.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely remove the element. Users are obviously clicking on it and likely getting frustrated because it doesn't do anything. I looked at your demo and I would also think an animated button shape was clickable. If I click on something and nothing happens, I assume something is broken.